# I am having problems retrieving associated data

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, lombok

I want to start a relationship but I get an error that I can't understand.

Person.java

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Personal implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String personName;
    private String personLastName;

    // comment old block 
    // @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    // private Address Address;

    // add 
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "person")
    private Address address;
}
```

Address.java

```java
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Address implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "Street")
    private String street;
    @Column(name = "Alley")
    private String alley;
    @Column(name = "District")
    private String district;

    // comment old block 
    // @OneToOne(mappedBy = "Address")
    // private Person person; 

    // add 
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @MapsId
    private Person person;

    
    public Adres(String street, String alley, String district, Person person) {
        this.street = street;
        this.alley = alley;
        this.district = district;
        this.person = person; 
    }
}
```

My Repository

```java
    public String createUser(){
        Person p1 = new Person();
        p1.setId(p1.getId());
        p1.setPersonName("testPerson");
        p1.setPersonLastName("testPerson");
        p1.setAddress(new Address("test","test","test",p1)); // ad person on address constructor 
        personRepository.save(p1);
        return "Save is successful";
    }
```

AddressService.java

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AdresServices {


    private final AddressRepository addressRepository;


    public Optional<Address> getAddress(Integer id){
        return addressRepository.findById(id);
    }
}
```

I want to see "person" using address 1. but I get error. When I do mappedBy the program gives an error.

***I am successfully saving to the database.***

***BUT!***  When I try to bring a member through the address table, or rather when I activate the use of  ***@OneToOne(mappedBy = "x"),*** my program starts to give an error.

ERROR :

```java
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putVal(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1012) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1541) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.getClassLoadingLock(ClassLoader.java:667) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:591) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:774) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:774) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:774) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2]
```

However, I still have the same problem! :) nothing has changed. the record to the database is successful, but it continues to give the same error when I want to retrieve the data

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the `Person` is the parent entity and the `Address` is the child entity in this relation, you should annotate your fields as following:

```java
@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable {

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "person")
    private Address Address;

}
```

```java
@Entity
public class Address implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId
    private Person person; 

}
```

The exception most likely occurred because you set the `mappedBy` on the wrong side of the relationship, namely the child.

Note that with the `@MapsId` annotation, you don't need to generate a new ID for your address entity as the ID of the parent class is used. This is the recommended approach [described by Hibernate maintainer Vlad Mihalcea](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/).

**Edit**
In your comment you stated that the exception occurs when you try to access the address via a controller. The problem here is that you have a infinite loop in the serialization of your entity (or DTO?) due to address -> person -> address -> person -> ... Check [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325387/infinite-recursion-with-jackson-json-and-hibernate-jpa-issue) for a detailed answer on how to fix it.

Comment: First of all, thank you! 

However, this way the database started to give an error in the saving part! :)

```java 

org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property [com.example.jpatrainingdemo.model.Address.person]
 at org.hibernate.id.ForeignGenerator.generate(ForeignGenerator.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
 at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
 at 

```

Comment: @smhylc you need to set the `person` field in your `Address` entity before saving it to the database. The message says `attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property` which indicated that the `Address` you're trying to save has a `null` `OneToOne` person

Comment: I added "Person" in the "Address" constructor. and the registration was successful. 

However, when I want to pull the address number 1 from the database, "localhost:8080/get-adress?id=1" 

I'm getting the same error again, nothing has changed.  

```java
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
 at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:na]
 at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016) ~[na:na]
 at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: yes I debugged it and exactly as you said, it goes into an infinite loop in the form of "address -> person -> address -> person -> person -> ..." in an infinite way. 

I examined the link you gave as an example, they use JsonIgnore there.  However, if I add JsonIgnore to the person variable in the address entity class, I cannot find a user in the address. Because JsonIgnore ignores that place and I cannot establish a relationship.  

I can see the associated address from the Person table. But I cannot see the staff from the address table. If I add JsonIgnore. I am not using DTO right now.

Comment: Then try the apporach with JsonManagedReference and JsonBackReference

Comment: The same problem persists. I am not sending a Json data. I am not using DTO. When I added JsonIgnore, JsonManagedReference or JsonBackReference, the problem did not improve in any way. 

Because adding them disables my request. When I call address 1, I want to bring all users who use address 1.